# Sorting Files in Array Correctly

Tags: arrays, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to sort images in the correct A - Z order but no matter which method I try I keep coming up stumps as it sorts as f1, f10, f100, f101, f5, f40 rather than f1, f5, f10, f40, f100, f101 - does anyone have some points as to where I am going wrong please?

```
Sub InsertImages()
Dim prs As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim txt As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim tmp As PowerPoint.PpViewType
Dim fol As Object, f As Object
Dim fol_path As String
Dim ImageMaxSize

'Store open presentation in prs
Set prs = ActivePresentation

'Cancel if slide show mode
If SlideShowWindows.Count > 0 Then prs.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit

With ActiveWindow
tmp = .ViewType 'Remember window display mode
.ViewType = ppViewSlide
End With

'Choose the path of the folder where our images are.
 Dim fileExplorer As FileDialog
    Set fileExplorer = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    'To allow or disable to multi select
    fileExplorer.AllowMultiSelect = False

    With fileExplorer
        If .Show = -1 Then 'Any folder is selected
            fol_path = .SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
        Else ' else dialog is cancelled
            MsgBox "You have cancelled the dialogue"
            fol_path = "" ' when cancelled set blank as file path.
        End If
    End With


Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, list As Object, listItem As Variant, strExt As Object

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(fol_path)

Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each f In oFolder.Files

If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(f)) = "png" Or LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(f)) = "jpg" Or LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(f)) = "gif" Or LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(f)) = "jpeg" Then
    list.Add oFSO.GetBaseName(f) & "." & oFSO.GetExtensionName(f)
End If
Next f

'Sort list a - z
list.Sort

Dim arr As Variant
arr = list.ToArray


'Call QuickSort(arr)

'Call Array_BubbleSort(arr)
Debug.Print Join(arr, ", ")
End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't that what alphabetical sorting normally returns?

Comment: Alpha sorting compares first letter to first letter then second to second.  To vba those are not numbers.  If you want it sorted correctly you will need to add the preceeding `0` to make all the numbers the same number of digits: `F001`,`F010`,`F100`,... then it will sort the way you want.

Comment: What you are talking about is called `Natural Sort`. See this blog article about it: https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments above correctly identified the problem. When sorting alphanumeric values, the sorter essentially iterates from left to right comparing values.

I actually ran into a very similar problem as yours, so I'll post my solution that you can hopefully adapt to meet your project needs. The major difference in my implementation occurs in the `Partition` function as part of `QuickSort`. Rather than compare two elements using a simple operater (e.g. `element1 < element2`), the Partition function calls a `Comparer(element1, element2)` function that contains custom logic.

In my implementation, `Comparer` splits the two elements into string and numeric portions, and then compares them individually.

Try working through my code below and see if that helps you in your specific case. I took some shortcuts (for example, I didn't test to see if my regular expression actually matches anything) because I knew the structure of my incoming values. You might not. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
'Test Function
Sub TesterWithStringArrays()
    Dim arr(0 To 9) As String
    arr(0) = "f5"
    arr(1) = "f10"
    arr(2) = "f7"
    arr(3) = "f45"
    arr(4) = "f13"
    arr(5) = "f3"
    arr(6) = "f27"
    arr(7) = "f62"
    arr(8) = "f9"
    arr(9) = "f4"

    QuickSort arr, 0, 9

    PrintArray arr
End Sub

'''
' Quicksort implementation below
'''
Sub QuickSort(ByRef arr() As String, leftIndex As Integer, rightIndex As Integer)
    Dim partitionIndex As Integer
    If rightIndex < leftIndex Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    partitionIndex = Partition(arr, leftIndex, rightIndex)
    QuickSort arr, leftIndex, partitionIndex - 1
    QuickSort arr, partitionIndex + 1, rightIndex

End Sub

Function Partition(ByRef arr() As String, leftIndex As Integer, rightIndex As Integer) As Integer
    Dim pivot As String
    Dim leftIter As Integer
    Dim rightIter As Integer
    Dim condition1 As Boolean
    Dim condition2 As Boolean

    pivot = arr(rightIndex)

    leftIter = leftIndex - 1
    rightIter = rightIndex

    While leftIter < rightIter
        leftIter = leftIter + 1

        ''' Because VBA doesn't short circuit AND operators, we have to
        ''' create this chain below. Without it, we can run into issues
        ''' where we index beyond the boundaries of the array
        condition1 = leftIter < rightIter
        If condition1 Then
            condition1 = condition1 And Comparer(arr(leftIter), pivot) = -1
        End If

        While condition1
            leftIter = leftIter + 1

            condition1 = leftIter < rightIter
            If condition1 Then
                condition1 = condition1 And Comparer(arr(leftIter), pivot) = -1
            End If
        Wend

        rightIter = rightIter - 1
        condition2 = rightIter > leftIter
        If condition2 Then
            condition2 = condition2 And Comparer(arr(rightIter), pivot) >= 0
        End If

        While condition2
            rightIter = rightIter - 1

            condition2 = rightIter > leftIter
            If condition2 Then
                condition2 = condition2 And Comparer(arr(rightIter), pivot) >= 0
            End If
        Wend

        'Debug.Print Str(leftIter) + ", "; Str(rightIter)

        If leftIter < rightIter Then
           Swap arr, leftIter, rightIter
        End If
    Wend

    Swap arr, leftIter, rightIndex
    'PrintArray arr

    Partition = leftIter
End Function


'''
' Helper function to print the array
'''
Private Sub PrintArray(ByRef arr() As String)
    Dim output As String

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        output = output + ", " + arr(i)
    Next i

    Debug.Print Mid(output, 2, 100)
End Sub

'''
'   Helper function to swap two elements in an array
'''
Private Sub Swap(ByRef arr() As String, idx1 As Integer, idx2 As Integer)
    Dim t As String

    t = arr(idx1)
    arr(idx1) = arr(idx2)
    arr(idx2) = t
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Returns:
'   -1 if element1 is less than element2
'    1 if element1 is greater than element2
'    0 if the two elements are equal
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private Function Comparer(element1 As String, element2 As String) As Integer
    Dim oReg As Object
    Dim matches1 As Object
    Dim matches2 As Object
    Set oReg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With oReg
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = False
        .ignorecase = True
        .Pattern = "([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)"
    End With

    ' NOTE: Should test that the regular expression returns a match
    ' before executing to prevent errors.
    Set matches1 = oReg.Execute(element1)
    Set matches2 = oReg.Execute(element2)

    'The string portion of the regular expression match
    Dim string1 As String
    Dim string2 As String

    string1 = matches1(0).submatches(0)
    string2 = matches2(0).submatches(0)

    If string1 < string2 Then
        Comparer = -1
        Exit Function
    ElseIf string1 > string2 Then
        Comparer = 1
        Exit Function
    End If


    'The string portions match, must compare the number portions
    Dim number1 As Integer
    Dim number2 As Integer

    number1 = matches1(0).submatches(1)
    number2 = matches2(0).submatches(1)

    If number1 < number2 Then
        Comparer = -1
        Exit Function
    ElseIf number1 > number2 Then
        Comparer = 1
        Exit Function
    Else ' Still equal
        Comparer = 0
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem where I needed a similar but far more generalized comparing function.
Spent hours looking and not finding anything, so I took @basodre's Comparer function and modified it to be able to parse any number of alpha/numeric combos and included toggles for decimal and negative numbers as well as case sensitivity.

If anyone finds they they need a general comparison tool use with your own sort function or replace @basodre's Comparer function with mine below code into

```
Private Function Comparer(element1 As String, element2 As String, Optional boolIgnoreCase As Boolean = True, Optional boolConsiderDecimalPlace As Boolean = False, Optional boolConsiderNegativeSign As Boolean = False) As Integer
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Returns:
'   -1 if element1 is less than element2
'    1 if element1 is greater than element2
'    0 if the two elements are equal
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim oReg As Object
    Dim matches1 As Object, matches2 As Object
    Dim str1 As String, str2 As String
    
    strNumericPattern = "\d+"
    If boolConsiderDecimalPlace Then strNumericPattern = "[" & strNumericPattern & "\.]+"
    If boolConsiderNegativeSign Then strNumericPattern = "-?" & strNumericPattern
    strFullPattern = "[A-Za-z]+|" & strNumericPattern & "|\W"  '"[A-Za-z]+|\d+|\W"
    
    Set oReg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With oReg
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = boolCaseSensitive
        '.Pattern = strNumericPattern
        .Pattern = strFullPattern
    End With

    ' NOTE: Should test that the regular expression returns a match
    ' before executing to prevent errors.
    Set matches1 = oReg.Execute(element1)
    Set matches2 = oReg.Execute(element2)

    If matches1.Count = 0 Then Comparer = -1
    If matches2.Count = 0 Then Comparer = 1

    iCnt = IIf(matches1.Count <= matches2.Count, matches1.Count, matches2.Count) - 1
    For i = 0 To iCnt
        str1 = CStr(matches1(i))
        str2 = CStr(matches2(i))
        
        If IsNumeric(str1) And IsNumeric(str2) Then
            If CLng(str1) < CLng(str2) Then
                Comparer = -1
                Exit Function
            ElseIf CLng(str1) > CLng(str2) Then
                Comparer = 1
                Exit Function
            End If
         ElseIf IsNumeric(str1) Or IsNumeric(str2) Then
            If IsNumeric(str1) Then Comparer = 1 Else Comparer = -1 'because number comes after alpha
         Else
            If str1 > str2 Then
                Comparer = -1
                Exit Function
            ElseIf str1 < str2 Then
                Comparer = 1
                Exit Function
            End If
         End If
    Next i
    'strings are equal
    Comparer = 0
End Function
'''
```