# Issue sorting dates with DDMMYY end of month

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a sub-routine which orders the ActivityDate column smallest to largest. The dates are formatted like DDMMYY so for example, 010621 would be the first this month, 300621 would be the last.

My issue is that I conduct reports weekly which means that on occasion, I will get the last day / days of the previous month. When this happens, those dates will be placed at the bottom, as 30 comes after 01 numerically e.g. 310521 will appear at the bottom of the spreadsheet, 010621 will appear first.

I know that I can add a column for month, use `=MID(date, 3, 2)` and sort the month number first but is there any simpler way of doing this?

This is my code for sorting the dates:

```
Sub SortDates()

    Dim ActDate As Long
    Dim ActDateLetter As String
    
    sheet = "Overall Activity"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Rows(1)
        Set b = .Find("ActivityDate", LookIn:=xlValues)
        ActDate = b.Column
        
    'Convert To Column Letter
    ActDateLetter = Split(Cells(1, ActDate).Address, "$")(1)
    
    End With
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Activate

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet).Columns(ActDate).Sort Key1:=Range(ActDateLetter & "1") _
    , Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Comment: Sort by the true _date_ value, not the day.

Comment: Why do you need `VBA` if date value is recorded as `DDMMYY`, just sort it but not working?

Comment: are you talking about dates or do you have strings (or numbers) that *look* like a date?

Comment: If the dates are stored as strings, you're running into the `Natural Sort` problem.  Since these are dates stored as strings, you can simply add a new column with the `DateValue()` of the string, sort based on the new column, then delete (you can do all that programmatically in VBA if needed). The other option it to implement your own sorting procedure.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62198108/3561813